# Can not execute powershell script from shared folder

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, shared-directory

I have a powershell script with following contents

```
$pass = 'password'|ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential('user@domain.com',$pass)
New-PSDrive -Name Storage -Root \\path\app -Credential $cred -PSProvider filesystem
```

I saved the script as a file on local machine and on shared folder(network).

When I execute the script on local machine, it maps to the appropriate path.
But if I execute script from shared folder, it shows me following errors:

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\path\app\Drives> \\path\app\Drives\Map.ps1
New-PSDrive : Unknown error (0x4c3)
In \\path\app\Drives\Map.ps1:3 Zeichen:1
+ New-PSDrive -Name Storage -Root \\path\app\storage -Credential $cred -PSP ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Storage:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Excepti 
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCom 
   mand
```

What is wrong? The shared folder is on windows server 2012.

### **Update**

I've forgot to mention, that the script and to map drive is on same server.
What I mean is, I have a server and it shares **two folders**. The first shared name is **app** and the second **storage**. On the shared folder app, I have a **script**, that should map **to shared folder storage**. Now I execute the script from shared folder app on a **client**, that should map to shared folder storage. But it does not work at all.

Comment: Is this PowerShell 2.0? (Check `$PSVersionTable['PSVersion'].Major`)

Comment: Excuse me, I've forgot metion, it is powershell v3. The execution policy is Unrestricted.